# control theory: Does proportional control add energy to a system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I am looking at a good tutorial on [PID control](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID), and I am a little confused about how control works. My question is really whether a proportional controller adds energy to the system to obtain some desired output, because from the before and after plots could not be generated without the introduction of a lot more energy to the system?

So assume I have a simple spring-mass system, meaning a 2nd order ODE. The transfer function after taking the Laplace transform looks like:

$$
\frac{X(x)}{F(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 10s + 20}
$$

Now if I use Matlab to simulate this system, I can use a unit step function, as the input. The unit step should just mean that the signal is set to $U(s) = 1$, so the error is the difference between the output and the input $Y(s) - U(S)$.  Here is a plot from the tutorial.

[image]

Now, the authors of the tutorial introduce proportional gain in a feedback controller. Now the new transfer function is

$$
\frac{X(x)}{R(s)} = \frac{K_p}{s^2 + 10s + (20 + K_p)}
$$

They set the gain coefficient $K_p = 300$. This is all very standard looking stuff for the transfer function. However, now the step response is so much stronger. My question is kinda how did the response ramp up so much?

[image]

So that is my basic question: if the step response is just a constant value of $u(s) = 1$, then how is the system going from an amplitude of 0.05 to almost 1.3 at one point, based upon feedback control? Like even with feedback that seems like a huge change in the system just by adjusting some constant input. I think I am probably misinterpreting the physics or something, so hopefully someone can set me straight. The math is easy to solve, but understanding whether the answer is sensible is what I am looking for.

Comment: controller modifies the input signal, sends it to the actuator which sends the actual modified input to the system.  The conversion from signal to energy/mechanical force is done by the actuator.

Comment: @Nasser Yeah, that makes sense. But I am confused because I thought a step input is fixed at 1. So even with an actuator, I imagine I should not be able to modulate the signal to greater than 1? Right. Or is the point that the step input is somehow variable and that the actuator can modulate that signal? I am using the Matlab `step` command right. So then the point is the actuator has some limit, but that limit is greater than 1. So the actuator can increase the input level up to the point where the error is minimized, but not above its upper limit?

Comment: @Nasser the tricky thing is also that the transfer function is different between the original system and the proportional control system. Physically the systems are basically the same, so the same dynamics should apply. But the difference in the function, and the $K_p$ in the numerator of the proportional transfer function seems to be the cause. But I am not sure what this means in a physical sense. How can the final amplitude be so much higher in the proportional system?

Comment: To be clear, are you wondering whether the closed loop proportional control adds energy *relative* to open loop without control? Or to some other closed loop control scheme (since you mentioned PID)?

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza I am interested in closed loop versus open loop. The plots above a a bit confusing--to me--because they look at amplitude versus something more physical like displacement. I get that in LTI systems if you input a sin wave you get out a sin wave with scaled amplitude and phase shift. I am just not sure how to interpret the change in amplitude though. Going from 0.05 to 0.95 is an 18 fold increase in amplitude. If the input is a step--which is fixed at 1--then how does an 18 fold increase occur?